# Вывод имён пользователя с формы на чистом php без js

Tags: php, form

Есть простая форма:

```
 <form name="test" method="post">
  <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
   <input type="text" size="40" name="user">
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```

И php код:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST ['user'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){

echo "<pre>";
echo $name; //пытался также $name[$i]
echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

Нужно чтобы без обновления страницы выводился каждый пользователь над формой друг за другом после submit. Но у меня при выводе имя пользователя заменяется новым при вводе нового в input-e.

Comment: "Пытаюсь реализовать" - как?

Comment: От того, что Вы убрали из вопроса слова "Пытаюсь реализовать", лучше не стало.

Comment: я написал, чтобы помогли реализовать логику такую. А ваш комментарий вовсе не полезен для этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если без php то так. Не тестировал может не корректно работать

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST ['user'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){
    $s = $_POST['namepost'].$name."<br />";
        }
    ?>


    <form name="test" method="post">
      <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
       <input type="text" size="40" name="user">
       <input type="hidden" name="namepost" value="<?=$s?>">
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
     </form>
     <?=$s?>
```

Comment: не, такое не работает.

Comment: сейчас потестил, всё работает

Comment: как именно не работает? ошибку выдаёт? или вы по другому хотели сделать?

Comment: вставил в свой код и не работает. А Ваш проверил - работает!

Comment: понял в чём была ошибка. У меня сначала был html в файле, затем php код - и это не работало. Я поменял местами и заработало. А почему так?

Comment: потому что всё поэтапно работает, сначала склеивает строки потом их выводит, и я не понимаю зачем это делать на php?

Comment: потому что стояла задачка сделать на php как вариант....ок, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("form").submit(function(){
  $("#names").html($("#names").html() + $("#user").val() + "<br />");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="names"></div>
<form name="test" method="post">
  <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
   <input type="text" size="40" name="user" id="user">
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```

Comment: в том то и дело что нужно на php это сделать.